# Xcode inline class/method documentation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, comments

I would like to document some of my classes
but in a way that I could press ALT + Click and show up a little popup with a description or return values, abstract or params , just the same way is built in Xcode for classes from the system.

Im **NOT** talking about making a HTML with all documentation like Doxygen does.
I want inline info of a method or class from the place its been implemented.

Comment: Sorry, Xcode's only built with doxygen helpers (@param, @return).